# How to join name and distance attribute to a point within a distance of the same layer

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, point, distance, buffer

I have a points layer (350 ish points), and basically want to know how many of these are in a 50 mile radius of each other. e.g. if point A has points B,D and P within 50 miles, I want the name and distance of B,D & P to be added as an attribute after A's row in the attribute table.  I know I can do this individually but I don't really want to have to repeat this 350 times!

Have tried buffering and spatial joining but it doesn't give me the desired output.

Comment: Generate Near table will get you half way through. Do pivot table twice on infid and near rank and join to original. You should realize that with N being max.number of matches to any point you'll end up with 2N additional fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Picture shows points labelled by their OID and name:

[image]

Table shows output of Generate Near table (points layer to itself) with neighbors' (within 1000m) names computed using join to NEAR_FID and FieldName computed using NEAR_RANK:

[image]

and inputs into Pivot tool:

[image]

Output of Pivot tool that can be joined to original points layer:

[image]

Picture shows odd points labelled:

[image]